# How to redirect a "bad" url that has a query string but does not start with a ? symbol?

Tags: .htaccess

There's a site that has had a bunch of bad links indexed and I've been asked to deal with it. There's one type of link that is giving me a headache:

```
http://www.example.com/category-display.html&Category_Code=some_cat_code
```

I tried redirecting to the home page:

```
Redirect 301 /category-display.html& /
```

That doesn't work because it adds everything past the & to the url.

In the best of worlds, I'd like to redirect to:

```
/app/mm.mvc?Category_Code=some_cate_code
```

So I tried using querystring and RewriteRule/RewriteCond but there's no query string without the ? that I can figure out, so I'm kind of stuck here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as **your top rule** in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^category-display\.html&(.*)$ /app/mm.mvc?$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```